# React Native - Press switch from outside the switch itself

Tags: react-native

I have a switch in my code which is working perfectly. I am trying to change the switch whenever the user presses anywhere in the view the `switch` is in. It currently works by changing the `state` which affects the `switch` but now it skips the `switch` animation.

Is there a way to press the `switch` from outside the switch itself?

Code:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.state.userPolicyAgree ? this.setState({ userPolicyAgree: false }) : this.setState({ userPolicyAgree: true })}>
    <View style={styles.switchContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.bold}>I agree</Text>
        <Switch
      style={styles.agreeSwitch}
      value={this.state.userPolicyAgree}
      onValueChange={newValue =>
        this.setState({ userPolicyAgree: newValue })
      }
      onTintColor="#F0813F"
      thumbTintColor="#FFFFFF"
    />
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: You could try to direct manipulate the Switch component. Add a ref to Switch component => <Switch ref={r => (this.switch = r)} /> Then when you onPress the TouchableOpacity =>  this.switch.setNativeProps({
      value: !this.state.userPolicyAgree,
    }); Then check if the aniamtion is there now, not sure if that works, just guessing :P

Comment: Don't think that is possible, since it is a wrapper on native element.